# How to become administrator user?

Tags: users, root, permissions, administrator

I'm new to this ubuntu 13.04 so in terminal i allways need to start my xampp as a root so please help me i wanna convert my current account as an administrator(root) user.

Comment: why not to use `sudo` to do the same just use `sudo <command>` this will execute the command as super user.

Comment: You might wanna move the *xampp* folder into your `HOME` directory. Normally you do not need administrative rights to start it.

Comment: @JJD: oh yes, you do; the servers run as different users, and you need root privileges to change into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first. You should not work and run your desktop as root. Full stop. It is a bad, bad idea. Especially if you want to run a web server. Forget about it. It is easy enough to do it: set a root password (`sudo -i` ; then: `passwd`) and log in as user root. But **don't do it**, there are better ways around it.

To start a web server (and xampp is just a bundle containing a web server, sql server and a few other things that you could have installed on your machine easily with your package manager), you need root privileges *for a brief moment only*. This is why you use `sudo` -- to become root for just the moment when your run the command. For example, if you have followed [these instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=223410) to install xampp, you can just run

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

If you are tired of typing in commands, create a desktop shortcut as described in the link above. If you are tired of typing in the password, edit your sudoers file. Type

```
sudo visudo
```

And at the end of that file, add the following line:

```
humanth ALL = NOPASSWD: /opt/lampp/lampp
```

(assuming that you start lampp as above and that humanth is your user name).

Furthermore, did you even read the [Linux XAMPP HOWTO](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html)? It shows very clearly [how to set up XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp-linux.html#fsl) as a service, so that you do not need to start it manually. In esssence, you just link the `/opt/lampp/lampp` script to `/etc/init.d`.

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/rc.d/rc3.d
ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp S99lampp
ln -s /opt/lampp/lampp K01lampp
```