# How can I create an X server that has a backing store?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, bash, xserver

So I am completely new to Ubuntu (I am running 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite). I am trying to remotely access my work computer but I keep getting an error reading:

```
"xevas: requires a X server that has a backing store"
```

I have read several post that say I should create a file called `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and put this in it:

```
Section "Device"

   Option "BackingStore" "True"

EndSection
```

The thing is, I have no idea how to execute this script and I'm not even sure I created the file properly. I am also not able to assign myself as root so I have been trying to run everything through sudo.

Could someone give me detailed instruction on how to set this up? This is the only bash scripting I really need, I can get around most other shells through sheer memorization.

Thanks

Comment: The file is being read by the Xserver when you start X Window system -- that is, if you log out and log in again, the file should be read. And yes, you are able to "assign yourself as root", because that is what `sudo` does. Try writing `sudo -i` in a terminal and see what happens. Can you please provide a reference to the post where you read about creating xorg.conf?

Comment: Using `sudo -i` did assign me as the root (sorry if I am using these terms incorrectly) and it allowed me to use the line `touch /etc/X11/xorg.conf` to try to create the empty file I'm just not sure about the following steps.

The post I was referring to in my original post is [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1690342)

Comment: To better understand what sudo is and what is its relation to root, you can take a look at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343687/how-to-become-administrator-user/343693#343693

Comment: However, before you rush to create an xorg.conf file (which you can do with `gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`), I would ask you to describe in detail what program you want to use to connect to a server, what OS runs on the server, and if possible, take a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the error message. I am using the terminal and X11VNC Server (potentially) to connect to my work computer which is running Ubuntu 13.04.